# Input File with url

Tags: image, file, symfony, url, input

I have an input of file type, and i want to allow the user to select an image on his computer or just give an url, and our server gonna download the image on himself.
I have a problem because I need to use only one input to upload local images and linked images.

Comment: Have you tried using a selection checkbox to chose whether a image or URL is going to be entered?

Comment: Why do you need to use only one input? That's silly, you could put 2 and hide one that could be shown with a link or button. (hiding the other field then)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for that,
Just keep the type of the input `TextType`, and on your view file

```
...
<button id="uploadButton">Upload Image</button>
{{ form_widget(form.image , { 'id': 'image-field' }) }}
...

<script>
..
 $('#uploadButton').click(function () {
        var button = $(this);

        if(button.text === 'Upload Image') {
            button.text('Set URL');
            $('#image-field').prop('type', 'file');
        } else {
            button.text('Upload Image');
            $('#image-field').prop('type', 'url');
        }
    });
..
</script>
```

Don't forget after submitting the form in your controller to check if the input with the name **image** is a file or an URL by using `if ($request->files->has('imageField') ....`